# Acrylic vs methacrylate

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

A native Spaniard here, asking about what we call *metacrilato* — this manufactured product:

[image: Coloured plastic sheeting]

What would you call it? I have seen use both acrylic and Methacrylate, maybe one of them is more technical.

Answer (score 5):

*Methacrylate* does seem more technical.  I'm a native speaker of English with a semi-decent vocabulary, and I had to look up what it meant.

*Acrylic* is a word everyone knows, but on its own, it's not specific enough--it can refer to *acrylic paints* or *acrylic fibers*, for example.  And I'm not sure if everyone knows that these materials can be referred to as *acrylic sheets* or *acrylic glass*.

I think *Plexiglas* is the most common term in the US, with the genericized *plexiglass* as a less common variant spelling.  Alternatively, it's sometimes referred to by the trademark *Lucite*.  In the UK, the trademark *Perspex* is instead more common.

---

EDIT: With ChrisH's help, I've come up with a pair of hopefully less misleading charts from Google Ngram Viewer, included here because everyone loves charts.  First, when set to "American English", Google gives us [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perspex%2Cplexiglass%2Cplexiglas%2Clucite%2Cacrylic+sheet%2Cacrylic+glass&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cperspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPerspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bperspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPERSPEX%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cplexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bplexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPlexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPLEXIGLASS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cplexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPLEXIGLAS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLUCITE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cacrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bacrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcrylic%20Sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BACRYLIC%20SHEET%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cacrylic%20glass%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bacrylic%20glass%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcrylic%20glass%3B%2Cc0), supporting *Plexiglas* as the most popular:

[image: AmE]

And [another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perspex%2Cplexiglass%2Cplexiglas%2Clucite%2Cacrylic+sheet%2Cacrylic+glass&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cperspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPerspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bperspex%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPERSPEX%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cplexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bplexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPlexiglass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cplexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPlexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bplexiglas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPLEXIGLAS%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BLucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blucite%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLUCITE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cacrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bacrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAcrylic%20sheet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacrylic%20glass%3B%2Cc0), with Google Ngram Viewer set to "British English", which suggests that *Perspex* is more popular over there:

[image: BrE]

Comment: A couple of issues with that ngram: you've used meth*yl*acrylate not methacrylate, which comes top, also perspex is on a par with plexiglass ([case-insensitive link](http://goo.gl/1fP5T2))

Comment: @ChrisH Ah, thank you--though you left out *plexiglas* with one `s`, which (as expected) comes out on top in American English.  (The generic *plexiglass* with two esses is less common.)  It seems that *perspex* comes out on top when you set it to British English.  Checking COCA and GloWbE confirm this: *Plexiglas* is a far more popular option in the US.  I'll update my answer presently.

Comment: I'd never noticed it with 1 *s* - I guess that's the trademarked form - maybe I'd always mentally corrected it!  a nice pair of graphs in the end.

Comment: Please add clickable links for the ngrams to the pictures

Answer (score 3):

These are acrylic sheets made of acrylic plastic, or, as sometimes called, acrylic glass (Polymethyl methacrylate).

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially the trademark [Perspex](http://www.perspex.co.uk/products/perspex-cast-acrylic-%281%29/) (also Lucite) is used generically for clear/translucent acrylic sheet  -and even for similar looking materials.

***Edit*** I think perspex is more common in the UK, while lucite (or plexiglass as in another answer) more common in the US, and ngrmas would appear to agree.

Answer (score 0):

A layperson, who is not an industrial designer, manufacturer, or other person that is professionally-involved in turned raw materials into products, will only ever say:

> plastic
>
> green plastic, orange plastic

I have found that some know the word 'acrylic'.

Comment: That may be, but the OP should be aware that "plastic sheet" is more commonly used as a synonym for "tarp" (tarpaulin). Without context "sheet of plastic" is more likely to evoke the meaning in the question.